# Google Maps API custom Icons with SSL

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google Maps Application and I want to put custom Icons instead of the generic red icon that usually shows up. But no matter what I do I can not set a different icon it always shows up as the red one. I read that you can not have https in the url for icons so I uploaded it to an image host but I still can't  get the icon to change. How do I get a custom icon on the map or do I have to go with bing?

```
function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 10,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
  }

  function codeAddress() {
  initialize();
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    range = document.getElementById("distance").value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            icon: "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png"
            position: results[0].geometry.location

        });

        lat1 = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        lng1 = results[0].geometry.location.lng();

      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
    load();
  }
```

Notice where it says:

```
icon: "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png"
```

Not matter what I change that too it always shows the red generic icon.

Comment: See the documentation on {custom markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#SimpleIcons), show us what your code looks like (should work).

Answer (score 0):

You can load marker images over both `HTTP` and `HTTPS` on your page. However, you will want to make sure that the scheme matches the containing page's scheme (or at least, make sure that you use `HTTPS` if the page does too).

It seems you have typo in your `MarkerOptions` object: a missing comma after the icon string.

```
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png",
        position: results[0].geometry.location

    });
```